# Maintaining consistency between Application UI and UI locators in WebDriver tests

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I am facing a common issue that most of us face while writing UI automation tests: 
**Strong coupling of automation tests with the AUT.** 
If an enhancement changes UI of a module, you have to go and spend a lot of time changing:
1. Either the code (logic) to test the module.
2. Or just the locator of an element.

If the change in UI is minimum, it's ok to manually replace the locators in the test. But it is not possible to do this if the change is very large considering deadlines and time constraints. 

I am trying to figure out a way to implement a tool / utility that will save my time from changing locators of any element in the web-app that I have stored in my locator map.
For example:
I have a locator for a search result list in my locator-map as:

```
searchResultsLocator=span[id="searchResults"] > ul > li[class="ui-menu-item"] > a
```

If a dev changes this by replacing the span with a `div` as a part of some patch, then I want this to get automatically get updated in my locator-map.

Has anybody worked on this problem? Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple/backup locators for each element. See my question here: [Pros/cons for using multiple locators per element in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16969772/2386700)

This doesn't automatically update your locators for you, but I was afraid attempting to do so might update them incorrectly. And then you might end up with a kind of false positives - tests which pass because they auto-updated to new locators, but locators for the wrong elements!

However, pre-defining multiple locators allows your test to continue running smoothly when one locator fails, but you can generate reporting/notification about the failure, and then still have time to do your manual updating of locators, as long as at least one of those backups continues working.

Comment: Really nice way of going around with that problem. But my problem is not exactly the same as you mentioned in your question. Your solution is useful if one strategy (xpath for eg.) doesn't work then try another strategy (css selector). But for me, it's about change of the element structure in the DOM.

Comment: Edit to above comment: It's about change of the element structure in the DOM when there is no certainty that the element will for sure have an ID. Even for cases like a checkbox is changed into radio button and it does not have an ID.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the problem is fixed or not, if not fixed you can try this..

I face the same issue is well but no more.
Create a file where you keep all the element references (if no ID is present you can use XPath) and then use a variable which takes value from this file instead of hardcoding it.

Do not create a single file for entire application, make sure you have related elements in a single file (say element of single page).

So when the UI changes you will have only one place to edit instead of entire test code.

Comment: I do not have a problem of maintaining locator values. I already have that functioning very well. I have made a .properties file which contains all the locators in a single location. I create a single hashmap of all the locators (name-values) and pass the hashmap across the pageobjects. I can then fetch the locators from the hashmap whenever I want to. My issue is different. It's about maintaining consistency between the UI changes developers make in the app and the locators I'm using.